# Too few arguments to function woocommerce_update_product_acf_save_post()

Tags: php, functions

I have an action in my functions.php to inform subscribers of an product update. I have a working function that accepts 2 arguments ($product_id and $product). However when I
press update on a product an e-mail goes out with the old values of my ACFs.

```
add_action('woocommerce_update_product', 'action_on_product_save', 20, 2);

function action_on_product_save($product_id, $product) {
    $updating_product_id = 'update_product_' . $product_id;
    if (false === ($updating_product = get_transient($updating_product_id))) {
```

I found a topic from someone with the same issue, but this solution won’t accept 2 arguments for some reason (probably my fault).

this is the code I found online which works if I uncomment all the $product related content further down. So with the code below my e-mail shows the updated ACF straight away. However without the productname as I can't add the $product argument without getting the Fatal error (see below)

```
add_action('acf/save_post', 'woocommerce_update_product_acf_save_post', 1000, 1);

function woocommerce_update_product_acf_save_post( $product_id ) {
    if (get_post_type($product_id) == "product") {
        remove_action('acf/save_post', 'woocommerce_update_product_acf_save_post');
        update_on_product_save( $product_id );
    }
}


function update_on_product_save($product_id) {
```

When I add the second argument however (see me change the arguments value to 2 below)

```
add_action('acf/save_post', 'woocommerce_update_product_acf_save_post', 1000, 2);

function woocommerce_update_product_acf_save_post( $product_id, $product ) {
    if (get_post_type($product_id) == "product") {
        remove_action('acf/save_post', 'woocommerce_update_product_acf_save_post');
        update_on_product_save( $product_id, $product );
    }
}

function update_on_product_save($product_id, $product ) {
```

I get an error;

`Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function woocommerce_update_product_acf_save_post(), 1 passed in /home/domain/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 307 and exactly 2 expected in /home/domain/public_html/wp-content/themes/hello-elementor-child/functions.php:50, referer: https://www.domain.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=7398&action=edit`

Comment: That's correct, acf/save_post only "passes one argument", you can check it here https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-save_post/

Comment: How can I use the $product to retrieve the product name inside that action?

Comment: I got it working with the following code!

``` 
function update_on_product_save($product_id) {

 global $product;
 $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
 $product_title = $product->get_name();
    $product_image_id = $product->get_image_id();
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with this! :)

```
function update_on_product_save($product_id) {

    global $product;
    $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    $product_title = $product->get_name();
    $product_image_id = $product->get_image_id();
```